# CAML query to retrive data from 3 lists present in three different site

Tags: caml-query, caml

I have a parent site X, and three child site A, B and C.
There is a list by the name "MyList" in all the list sites.

I want a CAML Query to retrieve the latest ten records,from "MyList"(now ten records should be coming from any of the three sites A, B or C, whichever is the latest)

I have to develop a visual web part in parent site X, to display those ten records.

Learned developers....Please help with this complicated CAML query situation

Answer (score 1):

You could achieve that using SPSiteDataQuery if you have particular list type or list base type.

SPSiteDataQuery can be configured to search in all lists of a particular list type or list base type.

1. The complete site collection
2. a particular site and sub-sites

   http://amjadk.wordpress.com/2012/11/03/spsitedataquery-understanding-with-examples-for-sharepoint-2010/

Answer (score 0):

You can try to use OOTB content query web part information about :
[which you can find here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa981241%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

also you can try :
[using LINQ](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff742311%28v=office.14%29.aspx)

Hope this helps!